# query to get the records have some_id and some_flag such that all same some_id must have all some_flag ='Y' in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, jpql

I am a beginner to sql and have tried to write the query but didn't get the desired result

```
select r1.some_id, count(r1.some_id) as ca   from (select r.some_id,
               r.some_flag,
               count(r.some_id),
               count(r.some_flag)
          from table1 r
         group by r.some_id, r.some_flag) r1  group by r1.some_id
```

my reqirement is like: whose some_flag is 'Y' for all the some_ids present in table, if one is Y and other is N then that some_id shouldn't come in result.

actual data is as:

[image: actual data]

and want result like below:

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid having to query the table twice by using `MIN` in combination with an analytic function.

```sql
SELECT id, some_id, some_flag
  FROM (SELECT t.*, MIN (some_flag) OVER (PARTITION BY some_id) AS should_return
          FROM table1 t)
 WHERE should_return = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option: per `some_id` MIN flag has to be equal to MAX flag, and it has to be `Y`:

```
select * 
from table1 a
where a.some_id in (select b.some_id
                    from table1 b
                    group by b.some_id
                    having min(b.some_flag) = max(b.some_flag)
                       and min(b.some_flag) = 'Y'
                   )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option to get you the results..

```
select *
  from table1 r
where r.some_flag='Y'
  and not exists (select 1
                    from table1 r2
                   where r.some_id=r2.some_id
                     and r2.some_flag <> 'Y')
```